# Force qmake to use C++11 without editing .pro file

Tags: qt4, qmake

I need to build a project using Qt4 and C++11.
Is there a way to force qmake to generate a Makefile which uses C++11 without editing .pro file (by adding CONFIG += c++11)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the official "Running qmake" documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-running.html), you can simply pass qmake assignments on the command.  In your case, it would be

```
qmake "CONFIG+=C++11" <myfile>.pro
```